# Working with File Connectors Mule

Tags: mule

Is there a limit to number of file connectors that can be used in the mule application.
I have 2 mule configurations included as below

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:ABC.xml" />
    <spring:import resource="classpath:XYZ.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

In ABC.xml i have file connectors defined as follows

```
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_1" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" workDirectory="${INBOUND_FAILURE_DIR}" workFileNamePattern="#[header:originalFilename]-#[function:dateStamp]-Processing" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_2" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_3" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" workDirectory="${FAILURE_DIR}" workFileNamePattern="#[header:originalFilename]-#[function:dateStamp]-Processing" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_4" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_5" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorABC_6" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />
```

In XYZ.xml i have file connectors defined as follows

```
<file:connector name="FileConnectorXYZ_1" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" workDirectory="${INBOUND_FAILURE_DIR}" workFileNamePattern="#[header:originalFilename]-#[function:dateStamp]-Processing" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorXYZ_2" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />
<file:connector name="FileConnectorXYZ_3" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"/>
<file:connector name="FileConnectorXYZ_4" />
```

The connectors in XYZ.xml do not seem to work. In the mule logs i see

[[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1700044407'.
    [[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1700044407'. Obj
    [[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1885360656'.
    [[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1885360656'. Obj
    [[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1448628158'.
    [[my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].FlowA.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1448628158'. Obj

But the files are not dispatched to the destination locations.

Sending below the mule configuration used from a previous post

**ParentFlow**

```
<flow name="ParentFlow" doc:name="ParentFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
<file:inbound-endpoint path="${SourceFilePath}"
    connector-ref="ParentFlowInboundConnector" 
    responseTimeout="10000" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="${REGEX}" caseSensitive="false"/>

</file:inbound-endpoint>

<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
<message-properties-transformer
    doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="Source_System" value="XXX" />
    <add-message-property key="publisherName" value="YYY" />
    <add-message-property key="FlowName" value="ZZZ"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<!-- This would store the message in the db -->
<wire-tap>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PERSITENCE.OUT"/>
</wire-tap>

<request-reply>
        <all doc:name="Move the message to all endpoints" enableCorrelation="ALWAYS">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathA"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathB"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathC"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="PathD"/>
        </all>
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="Response">               
        <message-properties-transformer>                    
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="4" />                
        </message-properties-transformer>               
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator" />
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>

</request-reply>
<component class="ProcessorA"  />
<component class="ProcessorB" />
<exception-strategy ref="Exception Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
```

**Child Flow**

```
<flow name="PathA" doc:name="PathA">
<vm:inbound-endpoint path="PathA" >
    <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
</vm:inbound-endpoint>
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">                  
    <add-message-property key="originalFilename_processing" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" />                
</message-properties-transformer>
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">                  
    <add-message-property key="directory" value="#[message.inboundProperties.directory]" />             
</message-properties-transformer>

<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="Destination_System" value="XXX" />
</message-properties-transformer>

<file:outbound-endpoint path="${OutPathA}" connector-ref="FileConnector_1" 
    tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>

<!--Send email alerts -->
 <all doc:name="All" >
    <processor-chain>
        <message-property-filter pattern="turnOffEmail=false" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VelocityTemplateResolver" doc:name="Java">
            <spring:property name="flowName" value="PPPP"/>
        </custom-transformer>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${SMTP_HOSTNAME}" port="${SMTP_PORT}" user="${SMTP_USERNAME}" password="${SMTP_PASSWORD}" to="${TO_ADDRESS}" from="${FROM_ADDRESS}" subject="${MAIL_SUBJECT}" cc="${MAIL_CC_ADDRESS}" bcc="${MAIL_BCC_ADDRESS}" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="emailVelocityMessageTransformer"  tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
    </processor-chain>
    <processor-chain>
        <message-property-filter pattern="turnOffEmail=false" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VelocityTemplateResolver" doc:name="Java">
            <spring:property name="flowName" value="FlowName"/>
        </custom-transformer>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${SMTP_HOSTNAME}" port="${SMTP_PORT}" user="${SMTP_USERNAME}" password="${SMTP_PASSWORD}" to="${MAIL_TO_ADDRESS}" from="${MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS}" subject="${MAIL_SUBJECT}" cc="${MAIL_CC_ADDRESS}" bcc="${BCC_ADDRESS}" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="emailVelocityMessageTransformer" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
    </processor-chain>
</flow>
```

Comment: Why so many connectors? Some are configured exactly the same...

Comment: David yesterday looking at the configuration noticed the same thing i reduced the number of file connectors. One for inbound and another for the outbound. The problem still exists ,what i noticed is for PathA and PathB the vm inbound endpoints are initialized and started as in the logs above. The files are not placed in the final file outbound endpoints.When i touched the mule configuration file ,the files where placed in the final file endpoints.It seems some blocking is happening when Mule starts up again the files are placed as desired. Can you give me some pointers where i should look at

Comment: I have added the mule configuration editing my earlier post. I was suspecting the request-reply router causing the issue but that is not the case. On restart of mule the file are delivered at the endpoints. It seems that it is queued up and not delivered at the endpoints initially.

Comment: Please note PathA,PathB,PathC and PathD are file drop offs.Additional functionality in the child flows is transformation of the files and some additional validations done.

Comment: Thanks for providing all this extra information, it will help understand your issue.

Comment: I tried changing the <dispatcher-threading-profile> at connector level but the blocking still exists. On touching or modifying the mule configuration file the files are moved or on restarting the mule standalone server. Still stuck up with this problem.

Comment: Any pointers where I should look.

Comment: Still stuck with this issue any pointers how to debug the problem